# analyze by row groups in R

Tags: r

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Averaging column values for specific sections of data corresponding to other column values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11562656/averaging-column-values-for-specific-sections-of-data-corresponding-to-other-col)

I would like to analyze a dataset by group.  The data is set up like this:

```
Group   Result   cens
   A    1.3        1
   A    2.4        0
   A    2.1        0
   B    1.2        1
   B    1.7        0
   B    1.9        0
```

I have a function that calculates the following

```
sumStats = function(obs, cens) {
detects = obs[cens==0]
nondetects= obs[cens=1]
mean.detects=mean(detects) 
return(mean.detects) }
```

This of course is a simple function for illustration purpose.  Is there a function in R that will allow me to use this home-made function that needs 2 variables input to analyze the data by groups.

I looked into the by function but it seems to take in 1 column data at a time.

Comment: This close to the most common question asked here on the [r] tag. There is also an `[r-faq]` tag. [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11562656/averaging-column-values-for-specific-sections-of-data-corresponding-to-other-col) will give you inspiration.

Comment: It is not quite the same because I have 2 variables that need to pass through the function.

Comment: Once you get the proper subset of the data, there is only one variable to pass to the function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Import your data:

```
test <- read.table(header=TRUE,textConnection("Group   Result   cens
   A    1.3        1
   A    2.4        0
   A    2.1        0
   B    1.2        1
   B    1.7        0
   B    1.9        0"))
```

Though there are many ways to do this, using `by` specifically you could do something like this (assuming your dataframe is called `test`):

```
by(test,test$Group,function(x) mean(x$Result[x$cens==1]))
```

which will give you the mean of all the `Results` values within each group which have `cens==1`

Output looks like:

```
test$Group: A
[1] 1.3
----------------------------------------------------------------------
test$Group: B
[1] 1.2
```

To help you understand how this might work with your function, consider this:
If you just ask the `by` statement to `return` the contents of each group, you will get:

```
> by(test,test$Group,function(x) return(x))
test$Group: A
  Group Result cens
1     A    1.3    1
2     A    2.4    0
3     A    2.1    0
----------------------------------------------------------------------- 
test$Group: B
  Group Result cens
4     B    1.2    1
5     B    1.7    0
6     B    1.9    0
```

...which is actually 2 data frames with only the rows for each group, stored as a list:
This means you can access parts of the data.frames for each group as you would before they they were split up. The `x` in the above functions is referring to the whole sub-dataframe for each of the groups. I.e. - you can use individual variables as part of `x` to pass to functions - a basic example:

```
> by(test,test$Group,function(x) x$Result)
test$Group: A
[1] 1.3 2.4 2.1
-------------------------------------------------------------------
test$Group: B
[1] 1.2 1.7 1.9
```

Now, to finally get around to answering your specific query! 
If you take an example function which gets the mean of two inputs separately:

```
sumStats = function(var1, var2) {
   res1 <- mean(var1)
   res2 <- mean(var2)
   output <- c(res1,res2)
   return(output)
}
```

You could call this using `by` to get the mean of both `Result` and `cens` like so:

```
> by(test,test$Group,function(x) sumStats(x$Result,x$cens))
test$Group: A
[1] 1.9333333 0.3333333
---------------------------------------------------------------------- 
test$Group: B
[1] 1.6000000 0.3333333
```

Hope that is helpful.

Comment: I used to have these groups in a array and use the apply function.  Now I want to put these groups in 1 dataframe and the apply function doesn't seem to work any more. The real function is actually much more complicated.  I just use the mean as an example.  The point is I would like to learn how to pass both result and cens variable to the function.

Comment: @Amateur - I've made some edits to my answer to hopefully give you some pointers and make things clearer.

Answer (score 2):

The aggregate function is designed for this.

```
 aggregate(dfrm$cens, dfrm["group"], FUN-mean)
```

You can get the mean value os several columns at once, each within 'group'

```
aggregate(dfrm[ , c("Result", "cens") ], dfrm["group"], FUN=mean)
```