# Selecting matching row values from a column (data frame) to create plots using a loop in R

Tags: r, function, loops, match, boxplot

I have a set of data that looks like this,

> ```
> species<-"ABC"
> ind<-rep(1:4,each=24)
> hour<-rep(seq(0,23,by=1),4)
> depth<-runif(length(ind),1,50)
>
> df<-data.frame(cbind(species,ind,hour,depth))
> df$depth<-as.numeric(df$depth)
> ```

In this example, the column "ind" has more levels and they don't have always the same length (here each individual has 4 levels, but in reality some individuals have thousands of rows of data, while other only a few lines).

What I would like to do is to have an outer loop or function that will select all the rows from each individual ("ind")  and generate a boxplot using the depth/hour columns.

This is the idea that I have in mind,

> ```
> for (i in 1:length(unique(df$ind))){
>
>   data<-df[df$ind==df$ind[i],]
>   individual[i]<-data
>
>   plot.boxplot<-function(data){
>   boxplot(depth~hour,dat=data,xlab="Hour of day",ylab="Depth (m)")
>
>   }
>
> }
>
> par(mfrow=c(2,2),mar=c(5,4,3,1))
> plot.boxplot(individual)
> ```

I realized that this loop might be inappropriate, but I am still learning. I can do the boxplot for each individual at a time, but I would like a faster, more efficient way of selecting the data for each individual and creating or storing boxplot results. This will be very useful for when I have many more individuals (instead of doing one at a time...). Thanks a lot in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about something like this?

```
par(mfrow=c(2,2))
invisible(
  by(df,df$ind,
    function(x)
      boxplot(depth~hour,data=x,xlab="Hour of day",ylab="Depth (m)")
    )
)
```

To provide some explanation, this runs a `boxplot` for each group of cases in `df` defined `by` `df$ind`. The `invisible` wrapper just makes it so that the bunch of output used for the `boxplot` is not written to the console.

Comment: Wow! Thanks a lot, this is great! One quick question. If I want to include the name of each individual (for example, ind 1, ind 2, etc) as a title, what would be the best way to go. I tried including main=paste(df$ind) inside the boxplot function but is not given me a title...

Comment: @user1626688 - try something like this replacing the boxplot line inside the above function: `boxplot(depth~hour,data=x,xlab="Hour of day",ylab="Depth (m)",main=paste("ind=",x$ind[1],sep=""))` and you should be good to go.

Comment: Do you think you can select two columns when using the by function in the code above. For example, not only selecting each individual but also a column that match lets say the specific season for this individual, resulting in a boxplot of depth vs. hour of day by ind x season?

Comment: @user1626688 - you can access any variables for the group once inside the `by` function - see my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13792951/analyze-by-row-groups-in-r/13793258#13793258 which will be a good guide I believe.

Comment: But only one variable at a time? What about if I want to access the information of two variables (individual AND season) to get the results, instead of just individual or just season? I like your other example, but I am not sure if it answers my question.

Comment: @user1626688 - `by` works like `by(dataframe,vars.to.split.on,function)` so your example would be `by(df,df[c("ind","season")],function)`